# Schwartzian Transform will not obvious faster if list count greater than 1M

Tags: performance, perl, sorting

I did a little test. Think we got millions strings like "Testor_**00**_pg_**1**_**8.7127**", and sort them by three number in string. I did a comparison between Schwartzian Transform and plain sort.

The plain sort:

```perl
sub test_sub_orig{
    return sort {
                    my ($a1,$a2,$a3)=($a=~/_(\d+)_pg_(\d+)_(\d+\.\d+)/i);
                    my ($b1,$b2,$b3)=($b=~/_(\d+)_pg_(\d+)_(\d+\.\d+)/i);
                    $a1 <=> $b1 or $b2 <=> $a2 or $a3 <=> $b3;
                } @_;
}
```

The Schwartzian Transform:

```perl
sub test_sub_trans{
    return map {
                    $_->[0]
               }
           sort {
                    $a->[1] <=> $b->[1] or
                    $b->[2] <=> $a->[2] or
                    $a->[3] <=> $b->[3]
                }
           map {
                    $_=~/_(\d+)_pg_(\d+)_(\d+\.\d+)/i;
                    [$_, $1, $2, $3 ]
               } @_;
}
```

And below is my result:

[image: Benchmark Result Trend(By count of strings)]

The X-axis is the count of strings. The orange line is Schwartzian Transform's "Fast multiple" than plain sort, then dark grey line is Schwartzian Transform's time cost.

**I wonder, why string count greater than 1M, get a such great efficiency degrade?**

**And, why we get largest multiple when count is small not larger? **

Comment: 1) The cost of sorting is proprtional to N log N, so an upward curve is expected no matter what. 2) I don't know what you mean by "fast multiple". Goolging that doesn't seem to produce anything meaningful. 3) ST uses a lot of memory, which could lead to swapping, which would greatly slow down a program.

Comment: Note that [this](https://pastebin.com/SY4cDk4q) should be faster. See also the Sort::Key modules.

Comment: @ikegami , forgive my poor english skill. If A func could executes 10 times/s, and B func could executes 30 times/s, then "fast multiple" of B to A is (30/10-1)=2.0;

Comment: Yuck. Don't compare rates. Compare times